# How do I load my buffered image and paint it onto my GraphicsPanel

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, awt

I have managed to be able to save an image but am unable to load one from a chosen file and then have it display on my graphics panel. I would also like it to prompt the user to save the current file first but am unsure how to tackle this.

I have three classes as follows:

**Driver Class**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class guiDriver {

    private GUIPanel panel;
    JFileChooser fileFinder;
    JFrame frame;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu fileMenu, helpMenu;
    JMenuItem item1, item2, item3, item4, about;
    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Are you sure you want to exit?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        guiDriver app = new guiDriver();
    }

    public guiDriver() {
        frame = new JFrame("Pen Simulator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new GUIPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        // there is a method to set minimum size
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        fileFinder = new JFileChooser();

        // File Menu
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        item1 = new JMenuItem("New");
        item1.addActionListener(new itemListener());
        item2 = new JMenuItem("Load");
        item2.addActionListener(new itemListener());
        item3 = new JMenuItem("Save");
        item3.addActionListener(new itemListener());
        item4 = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        item4.addActionListener(new itemListener());

        fileMenu.add(item1);
        fileMenu.add(item2);
        fileMenu.add(item3);
        fileMenu.add(item4);

        // Help Menu

        about = new JMenuItem("About");
        helpMenu.add(about);

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar); // setting the Frames menubar as the newly
                                    // created menubar
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    class itemListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem) (e.getSource());

            if (source.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("new")) {
                panel.clearGraphics();
            }

            if (source.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("save")) {

                BufferedImage img = panel.grabGraphics();
                File f = new File("savedimage.jpg");
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.setSelectedFile(f);
                int rval = chooser.showSaveDialog(source);
                if (rval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(img, "JPEG", f);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // int returnVal = fileFinder.showSaveDialog(null);

                }
                if (source.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("load")) {

                    BufferedImage img2 = panel.grabGraphics();
                    JFileChooser chooser2 = new JFileChooser();
                    File fileLoad = new File(chooser2.getSelectedFile().getName());
                    chooser2.setSelectedFile(fileLoad);
                    int rval2 = chooser2.showOpenDialog(source);
                    if (rval2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                        fileLoad = chooser2.getSelectedFile();
                        try {

                            img2 = ImageIO.read(fileLoad);

                            panel.setGraphics(img2);

                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        if (source.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                            Object[] options = { "Yes", "No" };
                            int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "Are you sure you want to exit?",
                                    "Graphics Application", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                                    UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"), options, options[0]);
                            if (choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                            if (choice == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GUIPANEL**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUIPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextField userCommand;
    private JLabel instruction1;
    private JButton instruct, clear;
    private GraphicsPanel graphics;
    private int penX, penY, angle;
    private int currentDirection = 0;

    private boolean penIsUp = false;
    private Color penColour;

    public GUIPanel() {

        graphics = new GraphicsPanel();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // SOUTH PANEL CONSTRUCTOR
        JPanel command = new JPanel();
        command.setLayout(new BoxLayout(command, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        instruction1 = new JLabel("Enter Command:");

        // BUTTO
        instruct = new JButton("Execute");
        instruct.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        clear = new JButton("Clear Graphics");

        // TEXT FIELD
        userCommand = new JTextField(10);

        command.add(instruction1);
        command.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(4, 0)));
        command.add(userCommand);
        command.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(2, 0)));
        command.add(instruct);
        command.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(2, 0)));
        command.add(clear);

        add(command, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(graphics, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        init();

    }

    public void init() {

        penX = graphics.getWidth() / 2;
        penY = graphics.getHeight() / 2;
    }

    public void moveForward() {

        String command = userCommand.getText().toLowerCase();
        int distance = Integer.parseInt(command.replace("forward ", ""));

        userCommand.setText("");

        if (penIsUp == false) {
            if (currentDirection == 0) {
                graphics.drawLine(penColour, penX, penY, penX, (penY - distance));
                penY = penY - distance;
            }
            if (currentDirection == 1) {
                graphics.drawLine(penColour, penX, penY, penX + distance, penY);
                penX = penX + distance;
            }
            if (currentDirection == 2) {
                graphics.drawLine(penColour, penX, penY, penX, (penY + distance));
                penY = penY + distance;
            }
            if (currentDirection == 3) {
                graphics.drawLine(penColour, penX, penY, penX - distance, penY);
                penX = penX - distance;
            }
            graphics.repaint();

        } else if (penIsUp == true) {
            penY = penY - distance;

        }
    }

    public void moveBackward() {

        String command = userCommand.getText().toLowerCase();
        int distance = Integer.parseInt(command.replace("backward ", ""));

        userCommand.setText("");

        if (penIsUp == false) {
            graphics.drawLine(penColour, penX, penY, penX, (penY + distance));
            graphics.repaint();
            penY = penY + distance;

        } else if (penIsUp == true) {
            penX = penX + distance;
        }

    }

    public void penUp() {
        penIsUp = true;
        userCommand.setText("");
    }

    public void penDown() {
        penIsUp = false;
        userCommand.setText("");
    }

    public void clearGraphics() {

        graphics.clear();
        graphics.repaint();

    }

    public void saveFile() {

        graphics.saveFile();
    }

    public BufferedImage grabGraphics() {

        return graphics.grabImage();
    }

    public void setGraphics(BufferedImage img2) {

        graphics.grabImage();
        graphics.repaint();
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("something")) {

                System.out.println("you typed something");
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("turnleft")) {
                currentDirection = currentDirection - 1;
                if (currentDirection == -1) {
                    currentDirection = 3;
                }
                userCommand.setText("");

            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("turnright")) {
                currentDirection = currentDirection + 1;
                if (currentDirection == 4) {
                    currentDirection = 0;
                }
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().startsWith("forward ")) {

                try {
                    moveForward();

                } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid command");
                }
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().startsWith("backward ")) {

                try {
                    moveBackward();
                }

                catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid command");
                }
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("black")) {

                penColour = Color.BLACK;
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("green")) {

                penColour = Color.GREEN;
                userCommand.setText("");

            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {

                penColour = Color.RED;
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("reset")) {

                graphics.clear();
                penX = 0;
                penY = 0;
                userCommand.setText("");
                graphics.repaint();

            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("penUp")) {
                penUp();
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("penDown")) {
                penDown();
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**GraphicsPanel**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

    /**
     * The default BG colour of the image.
     */
    private final static Color BACKGROUND_COL = Color.DARK_GRAY;

    /**
     * The underlying image used for drawing. This is required so any previous
     * drawing activity is persistent on the panel.
     */
    private BufferedImage image;
    int w, h;

    public GraphicsPanel() {

        Dimension resolution = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        int width = (int) resolution.getWidth(); // casting the screen width to
                                                    // integer
        int height = (int) resolution.getHeight(); // casting the scren height
                                                    // to integer

        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        // Set max size of the panel, so that is matches the max size of the
        // image.
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));

        clear();

    }

    public BufferedImage grabImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void drawLine(Color color, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    /**
     * Clears the image contents.
     */
    public void clear() {

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COL);

        g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        // render the image on the panel.
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void saveFile() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("Test.jpg"));
            w = image.getWidth(null);
            h = image.getHeight(null);
            if (image.getType() != BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB) {
                BufferedImage image2 = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics big = image2.getGraphics();
                big.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Image");

        }

    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: The `setGraphics` method of the GuiPanel class doesn't use the `img2` method argument in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method to your GraphicsPanel as follows :-

```
public void setImage(BufferedImage image) 
{
    this.image = image
    repaint();
}
```

and in the load area :

```
fileLoad = chooser2.getSelectedFile();
try 
{
      img2 = ImageIO.read(fileLoad);
      panel.setImage(img2);
} 
catch (IOException e1) 
{
   e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If you could upvote the post so I dont lose rep that would be great. Dont know why it got downvoted.